# Significato e uso di "rimpolpare" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs, neologism

Guardando le notizie su RaiNews, c'è stata una pausa in cui è apparsa una pubblicità di un prodotto cosmetico per il viso, nella quale si è usato un verbo che non conoscevo e che ha attirato la mia attenzione perché mi è sembrato molto curioso: "rimpolpare". L'ho cercato subito sul dizionario e ho visto che, secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rimpolpare/), significa

> Rifare la polpa, rimettere in carne o in polpa

Altri dizionari danno definizioni simili. Tuttavia, non credo che si trattasse di un prodotto per fare ingrassare qualcuno con la necessità di rimettersi in carne, per cui immagino che il termine fosse usato con un significato diverso: rinvigorire il viso?, farlo apparire più giovane? Veramente non lo so.

Inoltre, si tratta di un'invenzione dell'azienda che fa la pubblicità oppure ha un uso generalizzato con questo significato che mi è sconosciuto? Ricercando "rimpolpare" su Google mi appaiono prima di tutto molti siti web di dizionari e "simili" (Reverso, Glosbe, Woxikon, ecc.), ma si avanzo di parecchie pagine comincio a vedere siti che sembrano parlare di cosmetica. Non sono sicura, però, che questo voglia dire che questo "nuovo senso" del vocabolo si sia generalizzato.

Comment: Rimpolpare nel senso di dare volume e tono alle parti, in genere del viso, che non sono più così toniche.

Comment: Ad esempio: Iniezione di riempimento con acido ialuronico: 
*Iniettato sotto forma di gel, l'acido ialuronico aiuta a riempire le rughe (pieghe nasolabiali, rughe della guancia, rughe del mento, rughe del contorno della bocca etc.), a ripristinare i volumi (zigomi, tempie, etc.), a ridisegnare i contorni del viso o **a rimpolpare le labbra.*** https://www.filorga.com/it_it/cosmetici-anti-eta

Comment: @Gio: Quindi, "rimpolpare le labbra" significherebbe "dare più volume alle labbra"? Come quello che fa il botox?

Comment: E per il viso una cosa simile?

Comment: Sì, non ha nulla a che fare con “ingrassare”. Dare volume e tonicità sono le parole d'ordine nella cosmesi.

Comment: Hai presente una mela avvizzita? La buccia (pelle) diventa rugosa anche perché il volume della polpa diminuisce. Se rimpolpi (aggiungi polpa al-) la mela, la buccia torna più liscia.

Comment: @gio ...e da cui il mio commento con l'esempio di una cosa che ha polpa e pelle. E aggiungo che le pubblicità usano le parole molto attentamente, forse più di uno scrittore di libri. Può essere che *polpa* voglia, tra l'altro, richiamare la freschezza di un frutto.

Answer (score 2):

> rinvigorire il viso?, farlo apparire più giovane?

Assolutamente sì, in modo indiretto, limitatamente a tale contesto. In modo indiretto, dico, perchè lo scopo del cosmetico non è far ingrassare il viso (sarebbe controproducente credo), ma ridargli la consistenza polposa, cioè non flaccida, non cadente, non dura.

> Inoltre, si tratta di un'invenzione dell'azienda che fa la pubblicità oppure ha un uso generalizzato con questo significato che mi è sconosciuto?

Ho paura a rispondere a questa seconda domanda, perché cercare fonti per poter dire che non è un'idea personale è difficile e laborioso. 
Credo che, usando le tue parole, si tratti di un'invenzione dell'inserzionista. Ma invece di invenzione si può dire scelta, scelta fra le varie opzioni disponibili per spiegare il funzionamento del cosmetico in modo semplice, veloce (la pubblicità costa), forse differenziarsi dalla concorrenza, oppure adeguarsi, non lo so.

"Rimpolpare" contiene la particella "ri", che ricorda il ripristinare, ritornare, rinforzare, riequilibrare e simili. E si riferisce a "polpa", che potrebbe far pensare a un frutto fresco, liscio, giovane, gradevole alla vista.

Il verbo può essere usato in tutti i casi (figurati) in cui si voglia dare l'idea di aggiungere sostanza con scopo migliorativo, (es. rimpolpare un testo). Non trovo particolarmente felice l'associazione tra rimpolpare e il *ricostituirsi* di una persona: le persone non sono fatte di "polpa", la frase che hai letto sul Treccani, benché perfettamente legittima, mi comunica sfumature leggermente ironiche oppure molto fisiche e di registro colloquiale: faccio fatica a immaginare il mio medico che mi dice "lei è troppo magro e dovrebbe rimpolparsi".

Comment: Quindi, non ha un uso generalizzato nell'ambito della cosmesi?

Comment: @Charo non avevo capito bene la domanda. Nella cosmesi direi che è comune, o almeno non peculiare. Quando ho scritto "limitatamente ... contesto" intendevo dire contesto di cosmesi.

Comment: In ambito "cosmetico" si utilizza anche il termine "rassodare"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Sì, ma il significato di "rassodare" a cui ti riferisci appare chiaramente sul [dizionario](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rassodare/).